# Coordinate functions of Schauder basis

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, schauder-basis

If $X$ is a Banach space admitting a Schauder basis, then can we choose a set $\{e_1,e_2,e_3 \cdots \}$ as the basis such that there are bounded linear functional $f_i$ such that $f_i(e_j)=\delta_{ij}$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can; and in fact more is true.

For any basis $(x_n)$ of a Banach space $X$, the coefficient functionals $(x_n^*)$ defined by $x_n^*\bigl(\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty\alpha_i x_i\bigr)=\alpha_n$ are automatically continuous. Note that $x_n^*(x_m)=\delta_{nm}$. See, e.g., Joseph Diestel, *Sequences and Series in Banach Spaces*, pg. 33. (More can be said: the sequence $(x_n^*)$ is a basis of its closed linear span.)

The above remark also follows from the fact that for a basis $(x_n)$ of $X$, the projection maps $P_n:X\rightarrow X$ defined by $P_n\bigl(\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty \alpha_i x_i\bigr)=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \alpha_i x_i$ are bounded linear operators and $\sup_n\Vert P_n\Vert<\infty$. To see why the remark follows from this fact, note that $x_n^*=P_n-P_{n-1}$. 
The quantity $\sup_n\Vert P_n\Vert$ is called the *basis constant* of $(x_n)$.

An outline of one proof of 
this  basic fact concerning the projection maps for bases of Banach spaces is:

Consider $X$ as a sequence space, identifying $x=\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty \alpha_i x_i$ with its basis representation $(\alpha_i)$ equipped with the norm $\vert\Vert x\Vert\vert = \sup_n\Vert\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \alpha_i x_i \Vert$. Show that this is indeed a well-defined norm on $X$, and that
$\Vert x\Vert_X\le \vert\Vert x\Vert\vert$ for each $x\in X$. Then show that $X$ is complete under this norm. The Open Mapping Theorem will show that the norms $\Vert\cdot\Vert$ and $\vert\Vert\cdot\Vert\vert$ are equivalent.

See Diestel, e.g., for details.

Comment: I don't understand why each coordinate functional $x^*_n$ is automatically continuous: $\|\alpha_n x_n\|$ is not that obviously dominated by $\|x\|$ after all.

Comment: In " Joseph Diestel, Sequences and Series in Banach Spaces, pg. 33" Can you please explain how he find the inequality where he shows the coordinates of the sequence is Cauchy... I couldn't follow how the inequality is true.

Comment: @Mukil I think $$ |s_{pj}-s_{qj}|\Vert x_j\Vert =\biggl \Vert \sum_{k=1}^j (s_{pk}-s_{qk}) x_k  -  \sum_{k=1}^{j-1} (s_{pk}-s_{qk}) x_k\biggr\Vert$$

Comment: But from your inequality it still doesn't look to me that books inequality follows trivially.

Comment: Actually this inequality answers the question asked here. I think..

Comment: Just use the triangle inequality (I used "$j$" for the index to start); the rest follows trivially.

Comment: @David left  equality you presented is depending on the index you have kept. But I change the upper limit on the right side to some random n greater than j (j which is on the left )we have no inequality to use right? I have really done what you have said. But still I'm not getting it. Sorry to waste your time...

Comment: Call the first sum $S_1$ and the second $S_2$. Then the RHS is at most $\Vert S_2\Vert + \Vert S_2\Vert$. Also, note each of $\Vert S_1\Vert$, $\Vert S_2\Vert$ is at most the $\sup$ in Diestel.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124352/discussion-between-mukil-and-david-mitra).

Comment: Can you just tell me how is ||S1||,||S2l| less than sup in diestel?

Comment: @Mukil Because $\Vert S_1\Vert$ and $\Vert S_2\Vert$ are elements of the set the $\sup$ is being taken over.

Comment: I thought the definition of that sup is diestel is Sup of all subseqential limits. But your saying it is defined as for all n we get a sum and we are taking the sup of this sum(n) set?

Comment: Yes, that's right (so, sup of $\sum_{i=1}^1 , \sum_{i=1}^2, \cdots$).