# Prove that a Schauder basis consists of isolated points.

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, schauder-basis

Let $X$ be a Banach space. Suppose $(x_n) \in X$ is a sequence such that every $x \in X$ has a unique representation in the form $x = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \lambda_ n x_n$. Prove that the set $\{x_n\}$ consists of isolated points.

#### Details

- Such a sequence is a Schauder basis of the space
- The goal is to prove that each point in $\{x_n\}$ is an isolated point of the set $\{x_n\}$
- Tried to prove by contradiction, no success

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: I tried with contradiction

Comment: Do you mean that each point in $\{x_n\}$ is an isolated point of the set $\{x_n\}$, or of the whole space $X$? The latter is easily seen to be false, since normed spaces do not have isolated points.

Comment: each point in {xn} is an isolated point of the set {xn} consisting of all elements of the sequence

Comment: @user8795..As i see in your post,is this sequence a Schauder basis?

Comment: yes according to the question, the sequence acts as a Schauder Basis

Answer (score 1):

For a fixed $n$, the linear functional $f(x) = \lambda_n$ is continuous ([discussed here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/146730)). Since $f_n(x_n) = 1$, there is a neighborhood of $x_n$ where $f_n>0$. This neighborhood contains no other basis elements.